# Testing a ROR app without an Internet Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, webrick

Normally if I want to test an ROR app in Ubuntu, I run the rails s command and webrick initializes the server which I access by typing "localhost:3000" or whatever in the URL bar of my browser. However, I can't do this without an internet connection. If I'm in the air or just somewhere with no wifi, is there a way to still do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to do so if you load all assets (images, javascripts...) from localhost as well and you are not doing any requests to external services.

Comment: Try to check your proxy settings

Comment: iltempo, how do I load all assets? Right now, I'm navigating to my project directory in the terminal and running the rails server command from there...still not working. Wouldn't webrick load everything in the project directory by default?

Artyom, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Rails loads dependencies through the your OS's http libraries. I don't know the exact terminology, but it basically means your app will use any connection required to make your app run

To explain, this works in the same way as if you access `http://google.com` & `http://localhost:3000` - you still access through the browser, but your system doesn't mind if those URL's are local or public

To answer your question, you'll need to keep your db & assets local to your system. The simple way is to [install & run a MYSQL server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html), and [use `localhost` in your `database.yml` file](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/961978) to connect to it